# Boolean algebra show that LHS = RHS

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

> Prove the following equality with the laws of boolean algebra:

$$wx + w'y + xyz  = wx + w'y$$

[image]

Ok this should not be to hard but I can't see it. Anyone?

My attempt:

$wx + w’y + xyz$

Using the rule B18

$wx + w’y + xy + xyz$

Using the rule B16

$wx + w’y + xy  \neq wx + w’y$

Comment: Hint: If the RHS is true, then obviously the LHS has to be true. To prove that a false RHS implies a false LHS, divide into two cases according to the value of $w$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but that did not make much sense to me. :(

Answer (score 5):

Note that $$w x = w x(1+yz) = w x + w xyz,$$
and 
$$w' y = w' y(1+xz) = w' y + w' xyz.$$
Therefore,
$$wx + w'y = ?$$

---

Alternative solution:
Using B18, we have
$$wx+w'y+xyz = wx + w'y + \underbrace{xy + xyz}_{B16} = wx + w'y+xy = wx+w'y.$$

Comment: where, by the axioms the OP provides, $wx=wx(1+yz)$ follows from B5 and B8, and distributivity is B14; similar in the other line. Great!

Comment: Thanks for the  solution using B18. Shame on me for not seeing that...